# Why My android MediaPlayer can not be created

Tags: android

I am using Mediaplayer as follow:

```
myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.thatislove);
myPlayer.prepare();
myPlayer.start();
```

of course , I have add the "thatislove.mp3" to the res/raw .

then the simulator reported wrong message, the log is that:
 Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported 
 MediaPlayer create failed

Comment: your question is very unclear...

Comment: Does it work on a device? Also try converting your sound file to .ogg I don't have much experience with it, but with what little I have done with sound clips it seems as though things go smoother with .ogg rather than .mp3

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.thatislove);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you call create method you don't need to call prepare

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

read this

secondly for your problem try cleaning the project then build again.
Also you need to give a little more detail

Hope this helps :)